# A difficulty in understanding the Gram determinant.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

I did not understand why he represent $w$ as given in equation(3) in the following picture, especially from where the negative sign comes:

[image]

Could anyone explain this for me please?  equation(2) is given in the following picture:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe a bigger problem is that the vector $w$ is referred to, in the right-hand side, as $y$. Otherwise, it is as said in this script: expand the determinant on the last row, and you will get $y_1$ ... $y_n $ multiply exactly the same determinants that come out of Cramer's rule (potentially with shuffled columns). The minus sign comes from how many column swaps you need to get the correct $D_i $, compounded with the fact that you are expanding the last row.

Comment: yes I understood it by writing the case for $n=2$ and I got it, thanks @user8734617